# What compilers are used during installation of a package?

Tags: package, byte-compilation

When I download and install auctex, I read that

> The simplest way of installing AUCTeX is by using the Emacs package
>   manager integrated in Emacs 24 and greater (ELPA).  Simply do `M-x package-list-packages RET`, mark the auctex package for installation with `i`, and hit `x` to execute the installation procedure.  That's
>   all.
>
> The remainder of this section is about installing AUCTeX from a
>   release tarball or from a checkout of the AUCTeX repository.
>      Installing AUCTeX should be simple: merely `./configure`, `make`,
>   and `make install` for a standard site-wide installation (most other installations can be done by specifying a `--prefix=...` option).

In both ways, what compiler(s) are used?

In the first approach, the output of installation said

```
Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.87.7/auctex-pkg.el at Sun Sep 28 14:29:44 2014
Entering directory `/home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.87.7/'
```

In the second approach, I searched in the Makefile, and don't find gcc or g++.

Answer (score 8):

The compilation you refer to is usually called byte-compilation of emacs lisp. It generates a different and faster representation of functions for the emacs interpreter. Unlike compilation of C code using gcc where the resulting code is run directly by the hardware, byte-compiled code still needs the Emacs interpreter.

Emacs comes with a native compiler that can natively byte-compile an emacs lisp file. If you see the makefile, you should see a reference to `emacs --batch` which is calling emacs in non-interactive mode to convert `.el` files to byte-code. Interactively, you can achieve the same behavior using `byte-compile-file` or `byte-compile-buffer`.

You can read more about [byte-compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Byte-Compilation.html#Byte-Compilation) from the manual.

Comment: Thanks. Is the compiler `emacs --batch` then?

Comment: Yes, the compiler is `emacs` itself. `--batch` calls emacs in a non-interactive mode i.e. it performs the compilation and quits without additional user input.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases, the compiler used is Emacs itself.

When installing from ELPA, most of the build process is handled by `package.el`, therefore by the running instance of Emacs. `package.el` also loads directly the product of this build process, so that the package becomes immediately available.

In the Makefile-based approach, we have repeated calls to an external Emacs process. This can be seen in the Makefile with the following snippet

```
ELCC=$(EMACS) -batch -q -no-site-file -no-init-file -l lpath.el
...
lisp:   tex-site.el $(AUCSRC) $(STYLESRC) $(MULESRC)
    $(ELCC) -f batch-byte-compile $(AUCSRC) $(STYLESRC) $(MULESRC)
```